# MS Access - Data Type Mismatch in Criteria Expression

Tags: ms-access, type-mismatch

Using the query grid , comparing a String field with a Replace function result of another String field (same table) results in a Data Type Mismatch error when trying to filter for ‘Not Like’ (or <>).
‘TypeName’ confirms that all records are of type “String”.
The problem is caused by “MyStrCalc: Replace([StrA],".","_")” which is compared with StrB. StrA contains Null for some records. These are filtered out (Criterium = “Is Not Null”). But even when creating a new query that uses the result of the first, the same error occurs. I have also tried Nz.
If I use Make Table to create a new table where StrA “Is Not Null” and run effectively the same query, there’s no issue.
The data in the table changes frequently, so having to create a separate table every time (tens of thousands of records) is a real nuisance.
Any suggestions how to make the query work would be greatly appreciated.
(By the way – the version used is MS Access 2019 under Windows 10, both with latest updates.)

Comment: Edit question to show sample data as text table and the SQL statement.

Comment: Using Nz() works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your much appreciated quick reply.
I tried a few things as detailed below with the fourth attempt providing the desired result.

Source table t1:
| UID | StrA  | StrB  |
| ---:| ----- | ----- |
| 1   | Str.1 | Str_1 |
| 2   |       | Str_2 |
| 3   | Str.3 | Str_4 |

Desired Result = StrA<>StrB after replacing dots in StrA with underscores:
| UID | StrA  | StrB
| ---:| ----- | -----
| 2   |       | Str_2
| 3   | Str.3 | Str_4

q1_Bad:

```
SELECT t1.UID, t1.StrA, t1.StrB, Replace([StrA],".","_",1,-1,1) AS StrACalc
FROM t1
WHERE (((Replace([StrA],".","_",1,-1,1)) Not Like [StrB]));
```

Result: “Data type mismatch in criteria expression”.

q2_Runs_CannotFilter:

```
SELECT t1.UID, t1.StrA, t1.StrB, Replace([StrA],".","_",1,-1,1) AS StrACalc, [StrACalc] Not Like [StrB] AS StrACalc_NtEq_StrB
FROM t1
WHERE (((t1.StrA) Is Not Null));
```

Result: Runs, but filtering field ‘StrACalc_NtEq_StrB’ (SQL or after running query) results in “Data type mismatch in criteria expression”.

q3_OK_SQL_FilterFail:

```
SELECT t1.UID, t1.StrA, t1.StrB, Replace(Nz([StrA]),".","_",1,-1,1) AS StrACalc, Nz([StrACalc] Not Like [StrB]) AS StrACalc_NtEq_StrB
FROM t1;
```

Result: Runs, but filtering field ‘StrACalc_NtEq_StrB’ is only possible after running query. Adding “`Nz([StrACalc] Not Like [StrB]) AS StrACalc_NtEq_StrB`” results in “Enter Parameter Value | StrACalc”.
Note: If the result of the above is called in another query, the SQL filtering will work.

q4_OK

```
SELECT t1.UID, t1.StrA, t1.StrB
FROM t1
WHERE (t1.StrB) Not Like Replace(Nz([StrA]),".","_",1,-1,1);
```

Finally – Desired result:
| UID | StrA  | StrB  |
| ---:| ----- | ----- |
| 2   |       | Str_2 |
| 3   | Str.3 | Str_4 |